# Cannot run same script twice in same PowerShell session

Tags: powershell, sas, enterprise-guide

I'm writing a PowerShell script that will open an application, run a process, then close it, and then open another application, run a process, and close it.  (Ultimately more than two, but I'm starting small.)

I can run the following script, with no issues:

```
# Project Config
$projectName = "c:\temp\test3.egp"
$projectName2= "c:\temp\test4.egp"

# Start Enterprise Guide
$app = New-Object -ComObject SASEGObjectModel.Application.7.1

#Open the Enterprise Guide Project
$projectObject = $app.Open($projectName, "")

# Save the Enterprise Guide Project
$projectObject.Save()

# Close the Enterprise Guide Project
$projectObject.Close()

# Open the second project
$projectObject = $app.Open($projectName2, "")

# Save the second project
$projectObject.Save()

#Close the second project
$projectObject.Close()

# Quit Enterprise Guide
$app.Quit()

PS C:\temp> ./test.ps1
PS C:\temp>
```

However, if I run it a second time at that above prompt, without exiting PowerShell, I get errors.

```
PS C:\temp> ./test.ps1
Exception calling "Open" with "2" argument(s): "Path is not a directory 'C:': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
At C:\temp\test.ps1:9 char:27
    + $projectObject = $app.Open <<<< ($projectName, "")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
... more errors related to $projectObject not having a value, and then a second copy of each of these for the second attempt ... 

PS C:\temp>
```

It works fine if I exit from Powershell, and reopen Powershell, and run it again.

Restrictions that are documented primarily include only one Project being able to be opened at one time; however, clearly `$projectObject.Close()` works fine, because it does successfully run two in one script.  It's only when I've left the script and run it again that it's a problem.

Now, if I remove `$app.Quit()`, it *then* allows me to run it a second time in the same session; but I *do* want to quit the app (to ensure that any following run of the script isn't impacted by anything I just did; this is a programming environment, so things like setting session macro variables and such could have bad impacts).  I also don't entirely understand why the line `$app = New-Object ...` doesn't create a new instance of the application (and so why the prior run's $app quit is relevant)?

Is there something in PowerShell I am doing wrong here?  Or is this solely an issue with the API I'm using that I'll have to talk to SAS (the vendor)?

Comment: That is odd. Especially as I would expect all of your variables to have script scope only, so one run should not have an effect on another. I understand that removing `$app.Quit()` seems to make it work... but when it's included, have you verified that the application has fully quite? E.g. via Task manager. As the errors are related to `$projectName` perhaps `Write-Output` near script start or script end will yield more info.

Comment: Yes, I would think this is an issue you'd have to ask the vendor about.

Comment: @gms0ulman Unfortunately it doesn't look like I can tell.  Powershell seems to run the app under a different user ID, and I don't have admin rights to view processes from all users.  (Or else it doesn't directly expose to task manager?)

Comment: I did confirm that there is some difference between running the script twice vs. running the two projects in one script, in that it does not persist session macro variables; so maybe I can just leave out `$app.quit` and not worry about it.  Still odd, though.

Comment: Could you test by adding $app.Dispose() after your $app.Quit().

Comment: @TySavercool No such method, unfortuantely.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Might be worth doing a
`$app | get-method` 
and looking for a method that the devs left for such instances.

Comment: What is the powershell directory when you open a new powershell vs trying to re-run the script? if you CD to say `PS C:\Users\userProfile>` and then try to call the script does it run?

Comment: Nope... just the documented ones (new, open, profiles, quit, setActiveProfile).

Comment: @AustinFrench Doesn't make a difference.  (I'm CDing to the location of the script each time I reopen Powershell, but I can run it from wherever as long as I put the path in correctly.)

Comment: @Joe Unfortunately I don't have any experience with Enterprise Guide to help further. Reg ComObjects, I've mainly worked with Excel which shows as running in the task manager. Any objects/child-processes spawned by the script should run as the same user AFAIK. Running `$app | Get-Member` may reveal some properties/methods that could help. I second Bill_Stewart's comment to refer to the vendor as they're best placed to help. Good luck!

Comment: You could try adding `Remove-Variable app` as the last line of the script to dispose of the app before running it a second time. Or maybe `If(Get-Variable app){Remove-Variable app}` just before you create `$app` on line 6.

Comment: What will happens if you place the script in a PowerShell scriptblock in the following way: `& { <# place the script here #> }`? More details are [here](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-custom-scopes)

Comment: I am new to PowerShell and I have experienced this same issue. I am unable to run this code twice in the same session. I am just working with formatting, nothing big.
`code
WmiObject -ClassName Win32_BaseBoard | Select-Object Caption,Description,InstallDate,Manufacturer,Model,Name,OtherIdentifyingInfo,Product,SerialNumber,SKU,Version | Add-Content C:\Users\ComputerInfo.txt -Encoding unicode`

Comment: @JonathanBlaine You may want to ask a new question - this is pretty old and didn't really get a satisfactory answer, although I see there were some comments after I logged off that day that I didn't get around to addressing.

Comment: It is strange, I closed then re-opened PowerShell. It is now running both scripts. I guess problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your original PS session create a new PS session for each project: `New-PSSession`

More details and examples can be found on the Microsoft docs site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-6).